# how to use ngFor and innerHtml together?

Tags: angular

In my `app.component.ts` I have an array, in which both the text and also the html formats are defined:

```
this.testStrings = [
  '<b>title 1</b> Title Hier <FONT color="blue"><i>some texts hier.</i></FONT>',
  '<b>title 2</b> Title Hier <FONT color="blue"><i>some texts hier.</i></FONT>',
  '<b>title 3</b> Title Hier <FONT color="blue"><i>some texts hier.</i></FONT>',
  '<b>title 4</b> Title Hier <FONT color="blue"><i>some texts hier.</i></FONT>',
  '<b>title 5</b> Title Hier <FONT color="blue"><i>some texts hier.</i></FONT>',
  '<b>title 6</b> Title Hier <FONT color="blue"><i>some texts hier.</i></FONT>'];
```

I want to use `*ngFor` and `[innerHtml]` to show all the items above.

I tried a lot of method, such as:

```
<label *ngFor="let testString of testStrings" [innerHtml]="{{ testStrings }}"></label>
```

But none of them works. :-(

Thus I ask if somebody could help me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let testString of testStrings">
  <label [innerHtml]="testString"></label>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use interpolation with property binding. Try the following syntax:

```
<label *ngFor="let testString of testStrings" [innerHTML]="testString"></label>
```